# Enable Parralax effect on Laptops and Desktops only?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

Is there any way to only trigger the Parralax effect on laptop and desktop views?

Atm I have the following however, it doesn't allow an image to be displayed on some device browsers: Safari to be specific.

```
.parralax {

/* Full height */
height: 100%; 

/* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

My HTML solely references this in the section I want the Parralax effect.

```
<section id="home" class="home parralax bg-img fix">
```

Comment: Yes. You can overwrite the rules for the `class` and put in media queries so that it only affects Laptop and Desktop devices

Comment: Can you provide an example? 

I thought it would be something like this in a media query 

`.parralax {
enable: false; 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you put your external style sheet first in the document so it overwrites your parallax rules.

```css
/*Mobile 480px*/
/*Desktop 992px*/
/*Huge 1280px*/

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (min-width: 768px), (min-width: 992px), (min-width: 1280px) {
.parralax {
   /* Full height */
   height: 100%; 

   /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
 }
}
```

Comment: What does the `all` denote? 

Is that for all screen sizes?

Comment: oops yes I forgot to remove that. the all targets all media devices. But you only want the styles to affect for those specific widths. I modified the answer

Comment: Perfect. Let me try this :)